# Find witnesses proving that $f(x) = 2x^3 + x^2 + 5$ is $O(x^3 )$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Find witnesses proving that $f(x) = 2x^3 + x^2 + 5 \textrm{ is } \mathrm{O}(x^3 )$.

What do i need to do here?

Like step by step?

Comment: Which similar problem can you solve? Like step by step?

Comment: Well i know something about functions, however im not so familiar with big o and dont really know where to start.

Comment: Seems like a characterization of a question without context.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense, because when you ask if some function is O( some other function) you need to specify where x is going.

Comment: What if they refuse to declare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find constants $C$ and $N$ (these are your witnesses) such that
$$|f(x)| \leq C|x^3|$$
for all $x \geq N$.

An easy way to do this is change all of the variables in your polynomial to the highest occuring power, that is
$$f(x) = 2x^3 + x^2 + 5 \leq 2x^3 + x^3 + 5x^3 = 8x^3,$$
so we can take $C = 8$ and $N = 1$, which will be your witnesses.

Answer (score 1):

That $f(x) = O(x^{3})$ means that there are some $M \geq 0$ and some $X \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M|x^{3}|$ for all $x \geq X$.
But, since 
$$\frac{f(x)}{x^{3}} = 2 + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{5}{x^{3}} < 3$$
for large $x$,
we are done.